# How can I return a value of 1 or 0 depending on conditions of other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to return a value of `1` or `0` in cell `H1` depending on the following conditions being met -

```
E3>=60
F3>=60
G3>=6
```

I had used `=IF(E3>=60 AND F3>=60 AND G3>=6, [1], [0])` - but it is showing errors.

Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close.

In order to use the [`AND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-c192b0d8-0eeb-4768-a674-f84e6df9aefb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function, it must be in the correct syntax.

> AND(logical1, [logical2], ...)

So your formula should look like this...

```
=IF(AND(E3>=60,F3>=60,G3>=6), 1, 0)
```

This tells Excel `IF` the `AND` statement is `TRUE`, then use `1`, if not to use `0`. For the `AND` statement to be `TRUE` all the criteria `(E1>=60,F1>=60,G1>=6)` must be met.

*Note: don't use the brackets, [ ], around the 1 and 0. That is causing your error.*

Comment: For calculation purposes, you don't need the IF test or 1 and 0 values, just the AND expression.  If the AND expression is true, it will be handled as a value of 1; false will be handled as a value of 0.